# Using the native mongo driver in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, npm

There must be some Meteor 1.3 examples of opening a mongo database using
the native driver. Use the MongoDB Node.JS Driver to access collections in
another local database for example.  The new meteor 1.3 guides claim it is all possible.

Comment: mongodb provides this example // Retrieve
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  }
});

Comment: However in meteor using import { mongodb } from 'mongodb'; and var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient; fails

Answer (score -1):

Here's a slightly more updated answer:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

// Meteor offsets Mongo port by 1, so in case your application is running on 3000
const connection = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:3001/', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    poolSize: 1,
  });
  const db = await connection.db('testdb');
  // then you may create your collection of choice
  db.collection('testcollection');
```

FYI, you can also directly access the Mongo driver like so

```
import { MongoInternals } from 'meteor/mongo';

MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver()
    .mongo.db
```

Answer (score -2):

```
            import { mongodb } from 'mongodb';
            var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;



              MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test",function(err,db) { 

           var collection = db.collection('test');
           var doc1 = {'hello':'doc1'};
          var doc2 = {'hello':'doc2'};
           var lotsOfDocs = [{'hello':'doc3'}, {'hello':'doc4'}];

           collection.insert(doc1);
```